# Error installing Windows 7 on Lenovo laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-installation

I bought a new laptop (Lenovo with Core i5 2nd gen processor), which came with DOS.
Now I tried to install Windows 7 with a DVD on start up.

I got the message 'Press any key to boot from CD/DVD'.

I pressed a key, but nothing happened after that.
The same screen remained there even after a long wait.

Please provide some solutions.

Comment: Wait.. *new* laptop.. *Sandy Bridge i5*.. came with *DOS*?! I'm sorry if I'm rather sceptical of that. Are you sure?

Comment: yes. I am sure. Well, i opted it voluntarily, it actually  saved some bucks for me.

Comment: You changed your boot options to boot from DVD?